# Can you call an attribute with an f string through a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

def get_stat(symbol, stat):
  df = pd.read_csv(f"{symbol}.csv")
return df['close'].f"{stat}"() 

def test_run():
    for symbol in ['nugt', 'soxs']:
        for stat in ['max','min', 'mean']:
            print(f"{stat} Close")
            print(symbol, get_stat(symbol))


if __name__ == "__main__":  
    test_run()
```

The "stat" variable doesn't link between the "test_run" function and "get_stat" function which in turn won't let me call it in the `.f"stat"()` part. I am aiming for the results to look like this:

- max Close
- nugt ####
- min Close
- nugt ####
- mean Close
- nugt ####
- max Close
- soxs ####
- min Close
- soxs ####
- mean Close
- soxs ####

Comment: surely the line `print(symbol, get_stat(symbol))` should be `print(symbol, get_stat(symbol, stat))`

Comment: So you are trying to call the `stat` variable that you create in `get_stat` from your other function? The `stat` that is created in `get_stat` is outside of the scope of `test_run`, although its confusing because you create another variable named `stat` in your for loop in line 3 of `test_run`. You need to call `get_stat` and save the variable that is returned before you can use it outside of `get_stat`. But the `get_stat` function takes `stat` as an argument so i'm not sure where that comes from. What is the variable `stat`? Your code is very confusing, what is your goal with this program?

Comment: I want to have the code read through an 2 excel files (nugt.csv and soxs.csv), read the column "close" on both and call it with 3 different methods (max, min, mean) so that the result looks something like this:

max Close
nugt ####
min Close
nugt ####
mean Close
nugt ####
max Close
soxs ####
min Close
soxs ####
mean Close
soxs ####